# Dataflow SLA clarification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, amazon-emr

As you can see from the [docs][1] dataflow has a 99.5% SLA as opposed to a similar service like AWS EMR which has 99.9% for EACH single region.

That should mean that if a were to create a system using EMR, that replicates across regions I could calculate the "compound SLA" by doing 1 - (0.001)^n_regions and amp up the availability of my service, just like it is done with distributed system in HA mode.

Could I achieve the same thing by deploying multiple Dataflow jobs in several GCP regions?

EDIT: all of these considerations assume(maybe wrongly) that one region operational status should not affect other regions, which basically means that region are as independet as possibile.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks John for the time you took to write your response.
I actually do not agree with most things you said, and I also feel that maybe we are not understanding each completely.

First of all, I tried to move away the center of the topic to the failover as I wanted to understand the service guarantees and not failover techniques: in practice what I would like to set up could be even a manual failover to another region/zone, but that makes sense only if that other zone has a separate SLA.

Comment: @JohnHanley
What I then meant about “little bit of a joke” is that 99.5% avaialibility is the SLA of a single CE instance, which is not what I would use to power any production system, and is something that usually big player in the cloud game offer only for products that have 0 redundancy or integrated possibility of failover. And that makes sense, if I’m up to it I can host a multi regional distributed system and achieve better than 99.5% availability by adding redundancy to the system as I add instances in multiple zones/regions.

Comment: @JohnHanley Many companies require for regulatory reasons to have their services replicated across regions(some cloud providers) to achieve better reliability, but then I ask, does it make sense to do so if the SLA does not accurately reflect reliability gains?

Comment: @JohnHanley Also I surely don’t have a 24x7 but probably google has since (every other data service of theirs I could find except of dataproc, which has a really similar use-case to Dataflow) Cloud SQL(99.95%), Bigquery(99.99%), Spanner (99.999%), Firestore(99.999%) have all better SLA than Dataflow. I know that surely there are some technical reasons, but I just think that considering Google’s past achievement, having a 99.5 average SLA across all regions/zones for a single product is certainly not what I expected.

Comment: @JohnHanley PS: EMR and Dataflow refund policies have the same Downtime percentage slots, but AWS actually refunds you the full service if < 95%. Google seems to have a more sensible policy for Downtime since it requires only 5% of your request to fail for 10 consecutive minutes.

Also maybe I did not understand GCP SLAs at all, so if you may, be patient and if you have time I would love to listen to a more detail explaination on why I am wrong :D

Comment: Take your comments and fold them into your question. You have clarified a number of points. This way you will get better answers. I will delete my comment and rereview after your question update.

Comment: In the meantime, this is a good read: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/disaster-recovery/architecture